# I want to use JSQMessagesViewController without pod install! can I do it?

Tags: swift3, cocoapods, jsqmessagesviewcontroller, podfile

I open another project in my mac and this won't work because I got Error for JSQMessagesViewController and I think I should Install that so I want to install JSQMessagesViewController to my project ! I have problem with pod install can I use Another way? or there is no way Just That way?!
If I have to use this method please tell me how to use this in the terminal 
at the End when my project does not build its just because of JSQMessagesViewController pod file or not? thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little confused on your situation for what some of your questions are asking for but as to the on

> can I use Another way? or there is no way Just That way?!

You can clone the project and add it directly to your project. So not using pods. The drawback with this is updating. You will have to manually download the latest version and add it to your project every time you want new features that are released with this framework.

Let me know if you need more clarification or if I can help with your other questions I would just need more details.

Comment: I Installed pod Files and that work I did it wrong in the first time - and I Downloaded the clone too ! and it worked for me thanks for your Advices